# Anyway to profile my pc during startup to see what is going on?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a cutting edge very expensive custom pc with the best processor and gpu combo. Yet lately I've noticed some lag and freezing during start up like when explorer.exe and other programs load. I looked at task manager and cpu usage 0% and memory 15% Anyway to somehow profile the pc to see what's happening resource wise during start up?

Comment: Do you have external USB drives attached?

Comment: no, I don't have any usb drives attached.

Comment: I'd check the events logs, startup programs through msconfig.  also check if auto defragment is enabled. if not enable it.  if you ssd drive check if there is update.  for instance some samsung SSD had a problem that it gets slower with use, but there is a firmware update to fix it.  also check the fans if there are dust, clean it, clean dust and hair from motherboard and fans using air or some soft brush that doesn't leave people behind

Answer (score 1):

A slow startup does not always have to be a CPU problem but can very well be a delay caused by the initialization of hardware where software is just waiting for some operation to complete.

The best thing you can do to analyze the problem is doing the following:

Go to `Control Panel` -> `Administrative tools` -> `Event viewer`.

Unvold `Windows Logs` and open the `Application` logbooks by clicking on it.

At the right, press `clear log...`

From the popup choose <kbd>Save and Clear</kbd> and save the eventlog to a location you can remember.

Repeat the same steps for the `System` logbooks.

Immediately after, reboot your pc.

As soon as your pc is booted up, go back to the Event Viewer and look through the entries in both System and Application. Any Error or Warning is likely telling you why things are slowing down. If its not in there, then read the `Information` entries as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [SysInternals SysMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dn798348) tool.   You can setup this tool to log your bootup process.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 will tell you in task manager and I believe msconfig under the startup tabs which programs have a high impact.